# NopCommerce action not found on production works on localhost

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I have now run out of ideas on how to fix this issue. The action name is not available on production server for some reason. I keep getting 500 internal server error.
I tried using postman and restClient but each tool returns same error for live and works for localhost. What am I doing wrong?

Note: Everything commented is what I have already tried out.

**Controller Customer - Action code:**

```
    //[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]  
    [NopHttpsRequirement(SslRequirement.Yes)]  
    //available even when navigation is not allowed  
    [PublicStoreAllowNavigation(true)]  
    [HttpPost]  
    public ActionResult VerificationPin(string phoneNumber)  
    {  
         return Json(new {result = true, message = "Inside pin"});  
    }
```

**Ajax code to call the above function:**

```
var _data = { "phoneNumber": $("#Phone").val() };
                                        $.ajax({
                                            //cache: false,
                                            type:  "POST",//"GET",
                                            url: '@Url.Action("VerificationPin", "Customer")',
                                            dataType: "json",
                                            //data: JSON.stringify(_data),
                                            data: _data,
                                            success: function (data) {
                                                if (data.result)
                                                    alert("Enter the PIN code below.");
                                            },
                                            error: function (err) {
                                                alert(data.message);
                                            }
                                        });
```

Comment: Your current code is trying to a POST ajax request, but your action method is not decorated with Httppost !

Comment: `500 internal server error` means an exception is being thrown (if the action was not found you would be getting a 404 Not Found)

Comment: @Shyju I mentioned in the note that I have tried everything commented. Above JS code was for 'post' and then I used 'get' too. When I switched between methods, I updated server code accordingly. Both didn't work.

Comment: Have you checked nopCommerce event log?

Comment: @MarcoRegueira: As per my knowledge nopcomemrce cannot handle it *directly* if user has not added code to add log in custom code

Comment: @Hitin: There are many possible causes for *internal serer error* and you can check error in fiddler/postman. Please add error here!

Comment: @Div. Sorry to disagree.... Exceptions are logged in nopcommerce by default, check Global.asax.cs.  Fiddler or postman won't show any useful information without configuring the production server to disclose debug data. Hiding error details is a common security practice.

Comment: @MarcoRegueira no doubt that exceptions are logged in nopcommerce by default. But in this particular case I am not getting any logs in the database. So I am assuming that the error location is somewhere NopCommerce can't log the exception. But for some reason it's works in localhost.

Comment: 1. Is SSL enabled and working?
2. Check the event log of your server using the administrative tools.
3. Set custom errors mode to off, and see what error message is returned. (Then enable it again)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I get

```
    [NopHttpsRequirement(SslRequirement.Yes)]
    //available even when navigation is not allowed  
    [PublicStoreAllowNavigation(true)]
    [HttpPost, ActionName("VerificationPin")]
    public ActionResult VerificationPin(string phoneNumber)
    {
        return Json(new { result = true, message = "Inside pin" });
    }
```

An the ajax

```
        var postData = { phoneNumber: "01683715481" }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("VerificationPin", "Customer")',
            data: postData,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.result)
                    alert("Enter the PIN code below.");
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(data.message);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This doesn't work either, I tried it, still same issue. :(

Comment: Ok. Did you try by removing   

[NopHttpsRequirement(SslRequirement.Yes)]
//available even when navigation is not allowed  
    [PublicStoreAllowNavigation(true)]
    [HttpPost, ActionName("VerificationPin")]